# Calculating a weighted similarity

Tags: algorithm

I have 2 data rows and each of them have 4 fields

something like this:

```
        field1  field2  field3  field4
Row 1
Row 2
```

Now I have to compare these two records and calculate the similarity. I calculate the similarity for each field by deriving the cosine similarity.

So I end up with similarities something like this:
(0 signifying a week similarity and 1 signifying a strong similarity)

```
field1: 0.12
field2: 0.67
field3: 1.00
field3: 0.93
```

I can now find the total similarity by averaging the value but the problem is:
**I want to add weights to the fields**

so if field2 has a higher weight than field1, then the similarity of field2 will have a significant contribution to the average similarity.

Can you suggest a formula or algorithm to satisfy such a requirement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple,

1. multiply each of the 4 values by their weight
2. add the results together
3. divide by the sum of the weights

#### Examples

- In the example each of the fields can be thought to have an equal weight of 1

  ```
  ((0.12 * 1) + (0.67 * 1) + (1.00 * 1) + (0.93 * 1)) / 4 = 0.68
  ```
- Now if we want to make field2 worth 2x more than the other fields

  ```
  // Weights are (1 + 2 + 1 + 1) = 5
  ((0.12 * 1) + (0.67 * 2) + (1.00 * 1) + (0.93 * 1)) / 5 = 0.678
  ```
- If we want field 3 to have 100 times the weight (field 2 is still 2x)

  ```
  // Weights are (1 + 2 + 100 + 1) = 104
  ((0.12 * 1) + (0.67 * 2) + (1.00 * 100) + (0.93 * 1)) / 104 = 0.9845192307692308
  ```

#### Formula

```
((field1 * field1_weight) + (field2 * field2_weight) + ... + (fieldn * fieldn_weight)) / (field1_weight + field2_weight + ... + fieldn_weight) = weighted_average
```

#### Fractional weights

The formula works just the same if you give fractions as weights.  For example if you would like the weight of the 4th field to be weighted `150%` more then the other fields you can assign it weight `1.5`

```
// Weights are (1 + 1 + 1 + 1.5) = 4.5
((0.12 * 1) + (0.67 * 1) + (1.00 * 1) + (0.93 * 1.5)) / 4.5 = 0.7077777777777778
```

#### Weights are relative

You don't need to start with each of the weights set to 1, you can use 100 or 1000 if you like.

For example if the weights for all 4 fields were 100 the final average would be the same if they were all 1.

#### Further reading

[wikipedia: Weighted arithmetic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean)

Answer (score 1):

You just want to find the weighted average. Multiply each similarity by the weight, then add the products together, divide at the end by the sum of the weights to get the average:

```
total, totalw = 0, 0
for w,s in weighted_sims :
  total += w*s
  totalw += w
result = total / totalw
```